# How to return a value from a nested CompletableFuture without blocking?

Tags: java, future, completable-future

I'm having trouble returning car price value using `getPrice()` method because of the following error:

```
no instance(s) of type variable(s) U exist so that CompletableFuture<U> conforms to Double inference variable U has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Double lower bounds: CompletableFuture<U81345>
```

I want `getPrice` return `CompletableFuture<Double>` but instead it returns `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Double>>` because I'm returning a value from a nested future. I could call `.join()` on the nested future but I don't want to block the thread. This is my code:

```java
package my.package;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Test {
    public CompletableFuture<String> getCar() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Ford");
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> getCarMileage() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(100000);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Double> getPrice() {
        return getCar()
            .thenApplyAsync(car -> {
                // do something
                if (car.equals("Ford")) {
                    // do something
                    return getCarMileage()
                        .thenApplyAsync(mileage -> mileage * 0.2);
                } else {
                    // do something
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(42);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operation you're looking for ("return a `Container<U>` instead of plain `U`") is normally called *flatMap*, but the Java `CompletionStage` API uses other terms. As the API shows, [`thenApplyAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApplyAsync-java.util.function.Function-) is supposed to take a `T` and return a `U` which will be wrapped into a `CompletableFuture<U>`, but you can instead use [`thenComposeAsync`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenComposeAsync-java.util.function.Function-) and return your `CompletableFuture` (as a "flat" return type).

Comment: can you please give an example with the code in the OP? I can't get the code to work by swapping `thenApplyAsync` with `thenComposeAsync`.

Comment: @hitchhiker in the OP’s example, change `completedFuture(42)` to `completedFuture(42.0)`, so all branches consistently return `CompletableFuture<Double>`.

Comment: @Holger changing to `completedFuture(42.0)` still doesn't resolve the OP's original error.

Comment: @hitchhiker I assumed that you already applied this answer’s solution of using `thenComposeAsync`.

Comment: @Holger I did: `public CompletableFuture<Double> getPrice() {
    return getCar()
        .thenApplyAsync(car -> {
          // do something
          if (car.equals("Ford")) {
            // do something
            return getCarMileage()
                .thenComposeAsync(mileage -> mileage * 0.2);
          } else {
            // do something
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(42.0);
          }
        });
  }` this still doesn't compile

Comment: @hitchhiker you should replace the *first* `thenApplyAsync` with `thenComposeAsync`; the one, whose function returns a future rather than a value.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness below is the code using the `thenComposeAsync` following **@chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic-** answer and **@Holger** comment regarding returning `42.0` instead of `42` :

```java
package my.package;

import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

public class Test {
    public CompletableFuture<String> getCar() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Ford");
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> getCarMileage() {
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(100000);
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Double> getPrice() {
        return getCar()
            .thenComposeAsync(car -> {
                // do something
                if (car.equals("Ford")) {
                    // do something
                    return getCarMileage()
                        .thenApplyAsync(mileage -> mileage * 0.2);
                } else {
                    // do something
                    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(42.0);
                }
            });
    }
}
```